# bootstrab 3 datepicker not working while access from server side through controller using compile directive in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

bootstrab 3 datepicker not working in table that while access from server side through controller using compile directive in angularjs.
But if we put the table with datepicker in normal page(loading page), then it has been work well..what's wrong.can anyone give me some idea..
Thanks Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all datepicker you can use this code.classname should be same

```
$('body').on('focus',".date-picker", function(){
$(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: where the class coming from ".date-picker" bro