# jquery date picker is not work when i put datepicker on ready after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I want to know that my jquery-ui datepicker is not working in `document.ready` after an ajax function call. when I put on ajax complete its work successfully please help what should I do. what's the reason for not working

```
$("#ScheduledArrivalDate").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 2000);
        }, 0);
    }
});

function getPage(page) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: page,
        data: $("#frm").serialize(),
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#List').empty();
            $('#List').append($.parseHTML(html));
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        },
        complete: function () { 
           alert("complete");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post your html too!! are you appending any html in `success` of `ajax`?

Comment: if i just put this function ajax complete or ajax sucess it work fine

Comment: That I understood bro!! Can you post your `ajax` too here??

Comment: setTimeout(func, 0); !?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584546/bootstrab-3-datepicker-not-working-while-access-from-server-side-through-control/28584685#28584685)

Answer (score 0):

`$.document.ready()` only initiates after a page is loaded without ajax. When you replace/append html in an ajax call and you have a datefield in the new inserted html, you need to initialise it again (at least for the new inserted html block).

You could do this by calling `$.datepicker` in your success or complete function, like you already did, or by adding `$.document.ajaxEnd()` to your javascript file, what is initialized after every end of an ajax event (also on error).

Be aware not do double initiate the datepicker, especially when using ajaxEnd. This could lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

the code inside $(document).ready() will run only after page loads. While you are dynamically adding datepicker if I am not wrong. So do one thig. Take options in a variable like below:

```
var options = {
    beforeShow: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 2000);
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ScheduledArrivalDate").datepicker(options);
});
```

and in ajax call:

```
function getPage(page) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: page,
            data: $("#frm").serialize(),
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function (html) {
                $('#List').empty();
                $('#List').append($.parseHTML(html));
                $('#IdOfnewlyAddedDatePicker').datepicker(options);
            },
            error: function () {
        alert("error");
            },
            complete: function () { 
               alert("complete");
            }
        });
    }
```

Let me know if this not work or you are injecting html other than this.